# Magento 2 category not work properly

Tags: magento2, category, magento2.2.6

Most of category issued are about product not showing.
But I got a different issue here.
After I'm trying to solve some problem with the Porto theme.
Every category in my site start **showing all the products**.
I have tried virtual category, the filter shows correct result in backend.
But still, front end category keep showing every product in any category.
Search function work properly though.

I thought it was a compatible issue, so I upgrade from 2.2.4 to 2.2.6.
Checked the luma theme in 2.2.6, the issue is still there.
I forgot to test luma in 2.2.4.
The only thing I edited is Porto theme file because of the parameter name seems not match with magento and make it unable to install.
maybe it is because of other module that is with Porto theme?

I have found a similar issue in the Porto thread, but the site has fixed without mention the reason.
Is there any advice?

Thank you guys so much.

Comment: Ever find a solution to this? I have also ran into this issue using Magento 2.2.4